# Android background scale challenge on larger screen with hidden action bar

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-actionbar

I am developing an application for Android with a hidden action bar but even I have a solid  background (@android:color/white) when I run the app on a bigger screen sized phone (Galaxy Note 3), the area that I normally have the action bar is grayed-out (or I can say darker). I am hiding the action bar as the app starts (onCreate) and the layout is OK with the Nexus 5. Please find below my XML:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="247dp"
        android:layout_height="199dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/s" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="?"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/sb"
        android:textStyle="bold"
         />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Hello"
        android:textColor="@color/sbb"
        android:textSize="13sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editPhoneNumber"
            style="@style/EditTextPhn"
            android:layout_width="170dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:maxLength="15"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            android:textColor="@color/sbb" >


        </EditText>

         <Button
             android:id="@+id/buttonResetPhoneNumber"
             android:layout_width="38dp"
             android:layout_height="19dp"
             android:background="@color/sbb"
             android:clickable="true"
             android:text="Reset"
             android:textColor="@android:color/white"
             android:textSize="10sp" 
             android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="25dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonLogin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/sbb"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="Go!"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1**

One way is using Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen value in AndroidManifest.xml file. (Use the appropriate theme name whichever you used in your application)

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen">
</activity>
```

**Method 2**

Another way is, do this through code in the activity. In your activity do the following before calling setContentView() function

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);        

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Android 4.4 (API Level 19) introduces a new SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE flag for setSystemUiVisibility() that lets your app go truly "full screen."

[Using Immersive Full-Screen Mode](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html)